# Some questions about scipy.misc.imshow

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I just want to use python and scipy write a program achieve gray-level image histogram equalization, however, I find something is wrong when I use `misc.imshow` function.
I first read an image by `misc.imread` function and immediately I write a display function with `misc.imshow`, the image displayed is not the original one, it seems do the histogram equalization by default. Here is my code:

```
from sicpy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
......
image1 = misc.imread('./images/Fig2.jpg')
misc.imsave('./iamges/post_Fig2.jpg',image1)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image1,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

1. image1 is an image with low contrast.
2. post_Fig2.jpg is also an image with low contrast

**However the image displayed in figure window has a high contrast, significantly different from the two mentioned above.**

So I am wondering whether the `plt.imshow`
function do the histogram equalization automatically? or something is wrong with my code or my method?

Comment: Yes matplotlib imshow does a normalization by default. (see http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow). You can change this by passing your own normalization function to imshow, or by chaning the limits vmin and vmax.

Comment: The `plt.imshow()` function does a histogram equalization by default. However, the `misc.imshow()` function displays the image as what it is.